# jQuery loading spinner for loading all element loads completely

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

In Gmail log in, after click submit the log in form, we will see a progress bar until all of the html and javascript of google mail page loads completely.
How to make it with jquery? Thanks

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry, I didn't understand before... Thanks

Comment: No problem. It's not that obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+preloader&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft%3asv%3aIE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=#sclient=psy&hl=sv&rls=com.microsoft%3asv%3AIE-SearchBox&q=jquery+page+preloader&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=8eed59b92abfe5e3) got me a couple of hits. But I think [QueryLoader](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/) looks pretty neat. It lets you preload the whole page or parts of it.

To quote the author:

> This preloader has it all. Loading bar, custom animations and getting all images included in the web page.

I hope it was kind of you were looking for.